# Parsing a dataframe with a JSON structure on one of the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in the format below where **JSON** column is a JSON structure. The goal is to find a `Schedule8812` key nested under in `ReturnData` key object in the **JSON** column. If a `Schedule8812` key is found, it updates the **Schedule8812** column to `True` for that row, and `False` otherwise.

[image]

So far, I've been able to accomplish this by calling the function below.

```py
import pyodbc
import json
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

def iloc_df(df,col):  
    for i in df.index:  
        jdata=json.loads(df[col].iloc[i])
        # print(jdata)
        if 'Schedule8812' in jdata['ReturnData']:
            df.at[i,'Schedule8812'] = True
```

However, as the rows in my dataframe grows, the longer it completes. I'd like to switch it to a lambda expression but have been getting an error. Can someone point out to me a good reference on how to solve my lambda expression below thats getting an error?

```py
query['Schedule8812']=query['Schedule8812'].apply(lambda x:True if 'Schedule8812' in json.loads(query.JSON.to_string())['ReturnData'] else False)
```

Below is the error I'm getting.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test `JSON` column and in `lambda` use `x` instead `query.JSON`:

```
query['Schedule8812']=query['JSON'].apply(lambda x: 'Schedule8812' in json.loads(x.to_string())['ReturnData'])
```

Or if possible test subtring in column `JSON` use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
query['Schedule8812']=query['JSON'].str.contains('Schedule8812')
```

Comment: Thank you! The lambda expression you provided gave a syntax error by the way. But this `series.str.contains` did the trick, and much more cleaner! Adding it to my bag of tricks. A big thanks!

Comment: @KeithRivera - I remove `else False` later, now should working